Flatpak suddenly don't have write permissions
Around 3 days ago every flatpak stopped having write permisions.
Telegram could not start.
I can not write the database in KeePassXC.
I can not save files in Shotcut.
I've tried installing Flatseal to manage permissions.
I've tried flatpak override command to add directories.
I've succesfully saved a file in a network hard drive but failed to save inside my home folder.
I've read the documentation about flatpak permissions
My flatpak version is 1.14.6 and I'm using Kubuntu 24.04.

Have you made ANY changes or done any updates to the OS in last several days?

I've installed japanese language. I keep the OS up to date.

I've uninstalled ibus, ibus-mozc and the japanese language in my system. Now it works correctly. Such a weird bug.

You may want to report it as a bug if that is what you think it is.
